# How to access particular object in the vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I store 2 objects in each element of the vector `xySL`, i.e. `xySL[[i]]`: 1st object is `spl` and the 2nd object is `spl90`.

How can I access `spl` and `spl90`? I tried `xySL[[i]][1]` for `spl` but it does not work.

```
xySL <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10)
  xySL <- foreach(i=1:10, .packages = "sp") %dopar% {
    xy <- cbind(x,y)
    xy.sp = sp::SpatialPoints(xy)
    spl <- sp::SpatialLines(list(sp::Lines(Line(xy.sp), ID=i)))
    xySpatialLines <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2)
    xySpatialLines[[1]] = spl
    spl90 <- maptools::elide(spl, rotate=90)
    xySpatialLines[[2]] = spl90
    xySpatialLines
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `get()`?

Comment: @CephBirk: Thanks. I haven't used this function. Could you please post an example?

Comment: What is `numtrips`? 200?

Comment: @CepthBirk: this is the number of elements in the vector. Each element contains two objects: spl and spl90. At the moment, numtrips is equal to 10.

Comment: Hehe, I'm in the same Kaggle competition :) You should add a .combine parameter to your foreach. And then look into rbindlist() command from data.table package.

Comment: @LauriK: By the way, do you offer to use rbindlist outside of foreach in order to access each SpatialLines object?

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean exactly. You have a list of lists so i'd expect extraction to be done with `xySL[[i]][[1]]`